# How can a SPA application (Angular5) access a separate WebAPI (under AzureAD)

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, single-page-application

We have

- SPA App say, **SPAApp1** (Angular5 using ADAL package) protected by Azure AD. 

  **NOTE: There is no .NET component to this solution**
- WebAPI, say **WebAPI1** (.NET) protected by AzureAD.
- Created a scope with name **AllAccess** in WebAPI1
- Gave **SPAApp1** access to **WebAPI1** for the scope **AllAccess** in Azure Portal.

On login to SPA application, we get the ID_Token for the user.

1. How can we call the WebAPI1 from SPAApp1 passing the token having
   the right scope?
2. How this token is generated which can be used to
   access the WebAPI1 from SPAApp1?

As I know, to access a resource, we need to get a access token which would contain the required scope, aud(of the resource)? How can we get this access token in SPAApp

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using adal package, what you need is a resource(not the scope parameter which is needed by msal). The value of the resource should be `api://{your_webapi_clientId}`

You can refer the code [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/using-adal-js-with-angular4/) to get the access token.

Comment: I had missed adding in my question that I have given access of WebAPI to SPA application in Azure Portal. Just updated the question.

Comment: One thing that I can't figure is that the API config contains the API Clientid. So when the client-side SPA application sends the IdToken (containing user info, and the ClientId of SPA app) to the API, how can the API accepts this token? Also, reading from documentation from OpenIdConnect, it seems like we should always send the AccessToken and not the IdToken to the API. So how can we generate the Access token for the API in SPA and maintain the token